# Import xlrd values append to list

Tags: python, list, append, xlrd

Forgive the basic question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. I'm trying to import values from an Excel column using xlrd and turn them into a list. Any suggestions? Here's what I have so far, but the list returns all values with "number: 1.0" instead of just 1.0.

```
# Access Excel Workbook
datafile = "Household Debt Values.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(datafile)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

# Create CBSA list 
CBSAlist = []
for value in sheet.col(1):
   CBSAlist.append(value)
print CBSAlist
```

Returns: [number:1.0, number:2.0, number:3.0, number:4.0, number:5.0, number:6.0, number:7.0, number:8.0, number:9.0, number:10.0, number:11.0, number:12.0, number:13.0, number:14.0, number:15.0, number:16.0, number:17.0, number:18.0, number:19.0, number:20.0, number:21.0, number:22.0, number:23.0, number:24.0, number:25.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try split the value first:

```
# Create CBSA list 
CBSAlist = []
for value in sheet.col(1):
    CBSAlist.append(float(str(value).split(":")[1]))
print CBSAlist
```

Result

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0]
```

Comment: Returns 'list' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Hi Aaron, I just edited the code above. Now it reflects what I actually used to get the list shown above. Now the error message is 'Cell' object has no attribute 'split.' Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add a `str` method to the `Cell`, then `split` the `string`, then convert it to `float`.

Comment: Hi @chicago.coder: If my answer work,would you mind select it as the Answer! (There is a green check mark on the left side of my answer)(below the vote down.) Thank you!

Comment: Got it, sorry for the delay @Aaron.